# Divergence of a vector function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Calculate the divergence of the following vector function $$\vec{C}(\vec{r}) = \frac{r}{r^4}$$

---

Want to know if I am on the right track?

$$\hat{r}=\frac{\vec{r}}{|r|} \implies \frac{1}{r^4}\frac{\vec{r}}{|r|}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r^5} \therefore \nabla\cdot v=\nabla\cdot\frac{\vec{r}}{r^5}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{{-\frac{5}{2}}})+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{{-\frac{5}{2}}}) \ +\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(z(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{{-\frac{5}{2}}}) \ ...$$

thus the answer is $$\frac{-4}{(x^2 +y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}?$$

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.

Comment: @FengShao thanks, will the answer then be $$\frac{-2}{(x^2 +y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

Comment: No. The numerator is$-4$ rather than $-2$.